# Accessing weights

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I need to take weights of CNN model for every epoch separately. I have 100 epochs, so I need to see how the weights are changing.

Like, epoch 1: {weights},
epoch 2: {weights}   so on. I am doing "model.Cnn1.weight" , but it is printing all weights for that layer may be. Please give me any suggestions. Thanks

Comment: "How the weights are changing" isn't specific enough. Changes in what aspect of the weights do you need to see? For example, if your weight `w` is a vector of length 10, is seeing how `w[0]` changes enough? Or is it `w.mean()`? There are other options too so please be specific.

Comment: Welcome  This question would benefit from a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help users better understand the problem, the steps you've tried, and code that helps reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the weight values using the following code.

The apply method recursively applies a function to all layers in the model.

And parameter_print function check whether it is a linear layer or a convolution layer and print the weight values.

```py
def parameter_print(m):
  if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d) or isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
    print(m.weight)

model.apply(parameter_print)
```